# Class derived from std::exception throws invalid pointer error on what()

Tags: c++, exception

I tried to derive from `std::exception` like so:

```
class bad_number : public std::exception
{
public:
    bad_number(const char*);
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
private:
    const char* num;
};

bad_number::bad_number(const char * num) : num(num){ }
const char* bad_number::what() const noexcept
{
    std::string str;
    str.append("Invalid number format:");
    str.append(num);
    char* result = new char[str.size()];
    strcpy(result, str.c_str());
    return result;
}

//The function that uses the exception
long double convert(const char *str)
{
    char *endptr;
    double result = strtold(str, &endptr);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
        throw bad_number(str);
    return result;
}
```

The main function, in turn is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector<long double> vect;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        try{
            vect.push_back(convert(argv[i]));
        } catch (bad_number& e){
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  //free(): 
                             //invalid pointer: 0x000000000131bc40 ***
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97c8a1d84b355a44)

Why is the invalid pointer error printed? On my platform (Windows 8 + cygwin) it prints the actual `what()` return value. Does it mean that I have UB? If so, where in my code is UB?

In general, how can I fix that? I want a human-readable `what()` return value to be printed instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns the number of characters in the string, which does not include a null terminator. Thus `result` is one `char` too short, and `strcpy` writes past it.

Besides, it's really a bad idea to dynamically allocate a new `char` array everytime `what()` is called. This is made worse by the fact that `what()` is declared `noexcept`, even though `new` *may* throw.

Better construct an `std::string` in the exception's constructor, store it as a member variable, and just return its `c_str()`.

Comment: But str is being destroyd after leaving the block. So we'll get UB if return its internals..

Comment: @St.Antario edited, that wasn't clear. Thanks for questioning it :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify below what function code like this

```
const char* bad_number::what() const noexcept
{
    std::string str;
    str.append("Invalid number format:");
    str.append(num);
    char* result = new char[str.size()+1];
    strcpy(result, str.c_str());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: due to UB in the return statement -1

Comment: @St.Antario what do you mean by UB, and what's wrong with code ?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to data from a local scope. And the string operations can throw. So double-bad. Strange that this got a +1 from somebody.

Comment: I mean you returned the internal part of the object that doesn't exist outside the block-scope

Comment: We can return const char* from local string object , because it will be copied pointer not local internal . Can someone tell me , will this code ever crash ?    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char* ret(void)
{
    std::string str= "nitendra";

    return str.c_str();
}

int main(void)
{

    const char* test = ret();

    std::cout<<test<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Your pointer becomes a dangling pointer at the caller side because the thing it points to doesn't exist anymore. The code has undefined behaviour. It may crash. Or it may melt your processor. Or mail you a C++ book.

Comment: @mystic_coder: It is not about the pointer itself. It is about what that pointer points to. You are returning a pointer to memory that will be destroyed at function exit. So, you pointer value will be returned successfully, but by that time the *pointee* (the string) is already gone. The code you posted in the comment is broken in the very same way.

Comment: @AnT, I got it , modified answer.